# Calling a function from a different class from different package

Tags: scala, package

I have the following scala file, `test.scala`

```
package p1 {
    object ty {
       def f() = print ("p1.ty.f")
    }
}

package p2  {
    object ty extends App {
       def f() = println (" in p2.ty.f , in " + p1.ty.f ) 
        // calls above function 
        ty.f
    }
}
```

when I am trying to run the above code using `sbt` (with p2.ty on command line) it outputs the following:

```
p1.ty.f in p2.ty.f , in ()
```

while I expect the following :

```
in p2.ty.f , in  p1.ty.f
```

What causes this behavior - am I missing something?

Comment: I think you have missed parentheses. Actual function call will look like this: `p1.ty.f()` and `ty.f()`

Comment: i dont think so, because in scala, function with no params can be called  without paranthesis, correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p1.ty.f` does not return anything (it actually returns `Unit`) so it does not make sense to concatenate the result of this function with    another string `" in p2.ty.f , in " + p1.ty.f`. So as result, `print ("p1.ty.f")` would be executed first and will print `p1.ty.f` and then `println (" in p2.ty.f , in " + p1.ty.f )` would be executed and will print `in p2.ty.f , in ()` because `()` is a string representation of `Unit`.

So to achieve the desired result you need to write something like this:

```
package p1 {
  object ty {
    def f() = "p1.ty.f"
  }
}

package p2  {
  object ty extends App {
    def f() = println (" in p2.ty.f , in " + p1.ty.f() )
    ty.f()
  }
}
```

Comment: but why `print ("p1.ty.f")` executed first?

Comment: @ajduke becuause `print` function prints string to the console (stdout) and does not produce any results. It's only purpose is to perform this side-effect. Just take a look at it's definition: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Console.scala#L130

Comment: okay. p1.ty.f() is flushing its stream to console first then p2.ty.f(). i mean println here